# pandas - add values into column with header into mutltiindex (header) based on variables

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

First, I created a pandas multi-index data frame (df). Second, I have variables and a data frame (df_TV). I like to add values from "df_TV" into "df"  based on the variables "TV_Object", "TV_weight", "TV_room" and the index. Also, I like to add "TV" at the lowest level of the multi-index.

Creates the multi-index df:

```
header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
    ['Electrical Device', 'piece of furniture'],
    ['>10 Kilogramm','<10 Kilogramm'],        
    ['Kitchen', 'Living Room','Bathroom'],
    ], names=['Object','weight', 'room'])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['a','b','c','d','e'], columns=header)
df
```

Create the variables and df_TV:

```
TV_Object = 'Electrical Device'
TV_weight = '>10 Kilogramm'
TV_room = 'Living Room'

df_TV = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,1), index=['a','b','c','d','e'], columns=['TV'])
df_TV
```

I obtain, that the values will be added by index a,b,c, etc. and a new multi-index-header "TV" is under 
"Living Room" followed by the values. Thanks for ideas/solutions and your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

**Solution**

```
df[(TV_Object, TV_weight, TV_room)] = df_TV['TV']
```

**Output**

```
print(df.to_string())

Object Electrical Device                                                         piece of furniture                                                        
weight     >10 Kilogramm                      <10 Kilogramm                           >10 Kilogramm                      <10 Kilogramm                     
room             Kitchen Living Room Bathroom       Kitchen Living Room Bathroom            Kitchen Living Room Bathroom       Kitchen Living Room Bathroom
a                    NaN    0.495962      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN                NaN         NaN      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN
b                    NaN   -1.040295      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN                NaN         NaN      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN
c                    NaN   -0.653766      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN                NaN         NaN      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN
d                    NaN   -0.152420      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN                NaN         NaN      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN
e                    NaN    0.950787      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN                NaN         NaN      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN
```

Comment: wow, that works. the only thing that's missing is that "TV" (at level 3) is a new header in the multi-index-header. thank you Brandon

Comment: No prob. Please upvote/accept if this answers your question. :)

Comment: Do you have a solution how to insert „TV“ as level 3 header?

Comment: What is level 3? `room`?

Comment: ok, maybe level 3 is unclear. Level 0 = Object, Level 1 = weight, Level 2 = room and Level 3 than is TV in the multi-index-header. so I obtain that TV is also a header. in my real code i have not only TV, also other devices, which are listed under living room and i have to know which data depends to which device

Comment: Okay, I think I answered it in the answer below. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: no sorry, because it is not under the existing "Electrical Device" - it creates complete new column. later i will use groupby - maybe this will be a problem. maybe it is better to create a empty data frame merge all data frames like df_TV and than create the mulit-index-header... i also trying to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Another answer to address your level 3 request. You'll want to change your initial dataframe:

**Data**

```
header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
    ['Electrical Device', 'piece of furniture'],
    ['>10 Kilogramm','<10 Kilogramm'],        
    ['Kitchen', 'Living Room','Bathroom'],
    ['TV']
    ], names=['Object','weight', 'room', 'device'])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['a','b','c','d','e'], columns=header)
```

```
print(df.to_string())

Object Electrical Device                                                         piece of furniture                                                        
weight     >10 Kilogramm                      <10 Kilogramm                           >10 Kilogramm                      <10 Kilogramm                     
room             Kitchen Living Room Bathroom       Kitchen Living Room Bathroom            Kitchen Living Room Bathroom       Kitchen Living Room Bathroom
device                TV          TV       TV            TV          TV       TV                 TV          TV       TV            TV          TV       TV
a                    NaN         NaN      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN                NaN         NaN      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN
b                    NaN         NaN      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN                NaN         NaN      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN
c                    NaN         NaN      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN                NaN         NaN      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN
d                    NaN         NaN      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN                NaN         NaN      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN
e                    NaN         NaN      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN                NaN         NaN      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN
```

**Solution**

```
TV_Object = 'Electrical Device'
TV_weight = '>10 Kilogramm'
TV_room = 'Living Room'
TV_device = 'TV'

df_TV = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,1), index=['a','b','c','d','e'], columns=['TV'])

df[(TV_Object, TV_weight, TV_room, TV_device)] = df_TV['TV']
```

**Output**

```
print(df.to_string())

Object Electrical Device                                                         piece of furniture                                                        
weight     >10 Kilogramm                      <10 Kilogramm                           >10 Kilogramm                      <10 Kilogramm                     
room             Kitchen Living Room Bathroom       Kitchen Living Room Bathroom            Kitchen Living Room Bathroom       Kitchen Living Room Bathroom
device                TV          TV       TV            TV          TV       TV                 TV          TV       TV            TV          TV       TV
a                    NaN   -0.599330      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN                NaN         NaN      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN
b                    NaN    0.022242      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN                NaN         NaN      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN
c                    NaN   -0.214219      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN                NaN         NaN      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN
d                    NaN    2.121647      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN                NaN         NaN      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN
e                    NaN   -0.732355      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN                NaN         NaN      NaN           NaN         NaN      NaN
```